# SQL statement WHERE clause trouble with OR operator

Tags: sql

I have an issue with this SQL query:

```
SELECT user_id, scrap_id, scrap_text, profile_id,  add_date
FROM scraps 
WHERE profile_id=52 AND user_id=68 OR user_id 
IN(
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM profilecontact
    WHERE owner_id=68 AND profile_id=52
);
```

The problem with this query is this part where the OR operator comes in. I need SQL to think in the following way:

```
profile_id=52 <- This one should always be followed
user_id=68 OR user_id IN... <- The result may have user_id 68 OR a user_id that the sub query finds.
```

What SQL does now is it completely ignores this part:

```
profile_id=52 AND user_id=68
```

How can I use the OR and AND operators the way I need them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to organize your criteria with parenthesis.

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, scrap_id, scrap_text, profile_id,  add_date
FROM scraps 
WHERE profile_id=52 AND (user_id=68 OR user_id 
IN(
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM profilecontact
    WHERE owner_id=68 AND profile_id=52
));
```

This will treat the the user_id criteria as a single element and the profile_id as another, `AND`ing them together.